# Jquery Animate styling?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm still very new to JQuery. I don't seem to be able to get the following code to work.

```
$('.announcement_panel_button').click(function(e){
    $('#site_logo').animate(function(){
        $(this).css('margin-top', '5px')
    }, 5000);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Or if there are some other way to rewrite this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `animate` function's syntax is not right,  try it like

```
$('.announcement_panel_button').click(function(e){
    $('#site_logo').animate({'margin-top':'5px'},5000);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/g49UL/)

Check the syntax on [$.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

As @Tats_innit explained in his answer, `e.preventDefault();` might not be necessary if it's a simple button. It's needed when you want to prevent a default action like, `clicking <a> tags takes you to new url` or `form submit`.

Answer (score 1):

Hiya **demo**  http://jsfiddle.net/PCk7E/1/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/PCk7E/ http://jsfiddle.net/PCk7E/1/show/

There is a `click me` button underneath image.

I have made a minor change. Rest you can see above post as well for sample demo.

Good read for APIs:

1) http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

2) http://api.jquery.com/animate/

I would recommend to read both.

`preventDefault:` If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered. i.e. clicked anchors will not take the browser to a new URL. We can use event.isDefaultPrevented() to determine if this method has been called by an event handler that was triggered by this event.

**Code**

```
 $('.announcement_panel_button').click(function() {
    $('#site_logo').animate({
        'margin-top': +50
    }, 500);
    // e.preventDefault();
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for the resources. Reading now.